# Angular v5 issue compiling Bootstrap4 styles

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use Bootstrap4 for one of my project; however, when I set up my project with angular-cli following this tutorial (https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/building-an-angular-5-project-with-bootstrap-4-and-firebase-4504ff7717c1), I am getting this error in the terminal:

> ```
> ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","plugins":[null,null,null],"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
> Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser major
>     at error (/Users/Pastrana/GitHub/PersonalWebsite/PersonalWebsite/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:37:11)
>     at Function.browserslist.checkName (/Users/Pastrana/GitHub/PersonalWebsite/PersonalWebsite/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:320:18)
>     at Function.select (/Users/Pastrana/GitHub/PersonalWebsite/PersonalWebsite/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:438:37)
>     at /Users/Pastrana/GitHub/PersonalWebsite/PersonalWebsite/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:207:41
>     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
>     at browserslist (/Users/Pastrana/GitHub/PersonalWebsite/PersonalWebsite/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:196:13)
>     at Browsers.parse (/Users/Pastrana/GitHub/PersonalWebsite/PersonalWebsite/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/browsers.js:44:14)
>     at new Browsers (/Users/Pastrana/GitHub/PersonalWebsite/PersonalWebsite/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/browsers.js:39:28)
>     at loadPrefixes (/Users/Pastrana/GitHub/PersonalWebsite/PersonalWebsite/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/autoprefixer.js:56:18)
>     at plugin (/Users/Pastrana/GitHub/PersonalWebsite/PersonalWebsite/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/autoprefixer.js:62:18)
>     at LazyResult.run (/Users/Pastrana/GitHub/PersonalWebsite/PersonalWebsite/node_modules/postcss-loader/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:277:20)
>     at LazyResult.asyncTick (/Users/Pastrana/GitHub/PersonalWebsite/PersonalWebsite/node_modules/postcss-loader/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:192:32)
>     at LazyResult.asyncTick (/Users/Pastrana/GitHub/PersonalWebsite/PersonalWebsite/node_modules/postcss-loader/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:204:22)
>     at processing.Promise.then._this2.processed (/Users/Pastrana/GitHub/PersonalWebsite/PersonalWebsite/node_modules/postcss-loader/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:231:20)
>     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
>     at LazyResult.async (/Users/Pastrana/GitHub/PersonalWebsite/PersonalWebsite/node_modules/postcss-loader/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:228:27)
>  @ ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","sourceMap":false}!./src/styles.css
> ```
>
> 3:10-186
>        @ ./src/styles.css
>        @ multi ./src/styles.css

I've used Bootstrap before perfectly, so I do not know if there is an issue with the new beta version released one week ago.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is an error with the newest version of Bootstrap4. If you want to know how to fix it please visit: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9020